# php & mySQL connection error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I managed to get to phpMyAdmin and created a table .Then, I created the users with their username & password. Note that phpMyAdmin is running from a free website hosting area. It looks like it's done but I get this error message:

> Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
<?php
@session_start(); 
include(".login.php");
print_r($conf);
$con = mysql_connect($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['$username'], $conf['1000']) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("usersA", $con);
$prof = '000';
//$prof = $_GET['profile'];
$result = "SELECT * FROM usersA WHERE id = '$user_id'";
$q = mysql_query($result, $con);
?>
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($conf);`?

Comment: *"using password: NO"* your not sending the password you said you set up

Comment: As showdev said, whats in `$conf`, more specifically `$conf['1000']` ? Also, did you add the user to the database? (*Allowing the user to actually access the database*)

Answer (score 0):

try naming file properly..

`include("login.php");` instead of `include(".login.php");`

what is

```
print_r($conf);
```

use

```
$con=mysql_connect("ip(like http://1.1.1.1)","user_name","password");
```